# R, in a table, how to move rows at the bottom?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a table like this

A:

> **10 11 12 13 14**
>
> **20 21 22 23 24**
>
> 30 31 32 33 34
>
> 40 41 42 43 44
>
> 50 51 52 53 54

And I want to get a table like this:

B

> 30 31 32 33 34
>
> 40 41 42 43 44
>
> 50 51 52 53 54
>
> **10 11 12 13 14**
>
> **20 21 22 23 24**

That means that I need to take the first k rows of the initial matrix and put them at the bottom of the matrix.
How could I do it?

How could I get B from A?

Answer (score 1):

I have written [a function called `moveme`](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc/blob/master/R/moveme.R) that is part of [my "mrdwabmisc" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/mrdwabmisc) that might be useful here.

Usage in this case would be:

```
moveme(rownames(A), "1, 2 last")
# [1] "3" "4" "5" "1" "2"
A[moveme(rownames(A), "1, 2 last"), ]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 3 30 31 32 33 34
# 4 40 41 42 43 44
# 5 50 51 52 53 54
# 1 10 11 12 13 14
# 2 20 21 22 23 24
```

It offers "first", "last", "before", and "after" as part of the move commands, which can be chained as in the following examples:

```
moveme(rownames(A), "1, 4 last; 5 first")
# [1] "5" "2" "3" "1" "4"
moveme(rownames(A), "1, 4 last; 5 first; 2 after 3")
# [1] "5" "3" "2" "1" "4"
```

---

This answer assumes we're starting with "A" defined as:

```
A <- structure(list(V1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L), V2 = c(11L, 21L, 
  31L, 41L, 51L), V3 = c(12L, 22L, 32L, 42L, 52L), V4 = c(13L, 
  23L, 33L, 43L, 53L), V5 = c(14L, 24L, 34L, 44L, 54L)), .Names = c("V1", 
  "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: The `moveme` function seems no longer to be part of the `mrdwabmisc` package. I could find no function substituting it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but reasonable chance of success:

```
A[c( (k+1):nrow(A), 1:k) , ]
```

If k represents both the number of rows to move and w+k is also where you want them to be moved to *and* there are sufficient rows to allow this all to happen, then perhaps this untested code would succeed for the requested modification:

```
A[ c( 1:(w-1) , (w+k+1):(w+2*k+1), w:(w+k), (w+2*k+2):nrow(A) ) , ]
```

Comment: @BlondedDust: Thanks a lot. What if the part I need to move is not at row #1? What if I wanted to move rows from #w to #(w+k)?

Comment: I think we need more information. And we need to agree on terminology. I am using `k` for the number of rows, and you seem to now be using it for a position offset. You should build a reproducible example and do some pencil and paper work to clarify the task.

Answer (score 0):

```
myMatrix <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
k <- 2

rbind(
    myMatrix[-(1:k),]
    , myMatrix[1:k,]
)
```

Results in

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   11   12   13   14   15
[2,]   16   17   18   19   20
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    6    7    8    9   10
```